# How to update database without refreshing the page ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are creating a simple application using ASP.NET MVC. The app is all about uploading pictures and rating it, we have two buttons to vote, "like" and "dislike"

[image]

Each time I click the like button (green), the number besides it adds 1, and when I click the dislike button (red) the same thing happens, and the last number is the sum of these two, we are doing this using javascript.
This is mostly like YouTube's likes/dislikes counter, and now, what we want to do, it to update this counters to the database each time a user votes, if possible we'd like to do it without refreshing the page.

Comment: you should use javascript for this case

Comment: did you hear about ajax?

Comment: You're looking for `ajax`

Comment: http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building  there's a whole section on ajax

Answer (score 2):

Click a button, pass a variable and post to your method using ajax.

Something like this should get your started:

```
<button value="1">Like</button>
<button value="-1">Dislike</button>
<Script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        var xButtonValue = $(this).val();
        $.post("YourController.whatever",
        {
            value: xButtonValue,
        },
        function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
</Script>
```

Comment: `ServerSideScript` with MVC, are you sure?

Comment: @teovankot MVC - the C being controller. Generally executes code server side...am I incorrect?

Comment: @teovankot client side has no idea what server language or framework is used (and doesn't care). All it needs is a valid url