# how to make the page not refresh every time when I press a like or dislike button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to add like or dislike to image on my page. I have a possibility to add them but when I click like or dislike every time page refresh and it is so irritate

I tried solution from:
[Avoiding Page Refresh Event while Clicking Button Multiple times in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550660/avoiding-page-refresh-event-while-clicking-button-multiple-times-in-asp-net)
http://geekswithblogs.net/Vipin/archive/2011/06/08/detecting-browser-refresh-from-code-behind-in-.net.aspx
[How to update database without refreshing the page ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741741/how-to-update-database-without-refreshing-the-page-asp-net)
but it didn't help

method like and dislike in my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Like(int id)
{
    var memy = db.Memy.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id_mema == id);
    memy.Like++;
    if (id != memy.Id_mema)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Update(memy);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Dislike(int id)
{
    var memy = db.Memy.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id_mema == id);
    memy.Dislike++;
    if (id != memy.Id_mema)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Update(memy);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Views Index where I dispaly amount of like and dislike

```
<p class="opis">@item.Description</p>
<p class="item-id">@item.Id_mema</p>
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id_mema">Delete</a>
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id_mema">Edit</a>
<a asp-action="Like" asp-route-id="@item.Id_mema">Like</a> @item.Like

<a asp-action="Dislike" asp-route-id="@item.Id_mema">Dislike</a> @item.Dislike
```

Somebody know how to make add like and dislike without every time refresh page?

Comment: You need to make the `Like` and `Dislike` action methods as API's and then call them from javascript. Your current implementation is an ordinary ASP.NET action methods that returns complete view.

Comment: what you mean by making like and dislike action methods as API? I should API Controller or something? sorry maybe I ask a simple question but I am new in this technology and I do not know this >>